# Stop contributors from editing standard posts but allow them to edit a custom post type

Tags: user-roles

I need to stop any site user who is a 'contributor' from editing the standard posts, but I want them to be able to edit a custom post type called courses. Here is my code that I have so far, it is not working:
**Activation of theme:**

```
   function remove_editor_read_private_posts(){
 global $wp_roles;
 $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'contributor', 'edit_post' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_editor_read_private_posts' );
```

The above code needs to remove the ability to edit standard posts, but allow  contributors to edit a custom post type called courses. Before this code contributors can edit both standard and the custom post type called courses.

**Deactivation of theme:**

```
 function remove_editor_read_private_poststwo(){
     global $wp_roles;
     $wp_roles->add_cap( 'contributor', 'edit_post' );
    }

     add_action( 'switch_theme', 'remove_editor_read_private_poststwo' );
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Hint

The changes on roles and no layout-topics should not a part of a Theme, is much more a topic for a plugin. maybe you think about this topic on point like maintenance, switch of theme and hooks for activation - easier on plugins.

#### For your problem

You must add the roles new capabilities for your custom post type and remove the capabilities for type `post`. On activation change the roles for the follow capabilities.

```
foreach ( self::$todo_roles as $role ) {            
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_' . self::$post_type_1 );
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_' . self::$post_type_1 ); 
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'delete_' . self::$post_type_1 );
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_others_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );    
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'publish_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'read_private_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );   
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'delete_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' ); 
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'delete_private_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' ); 
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'delete_published_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'delete_others_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );  
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_private_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' );
     $wp_roles->add_cap( $role, 'edit_published_' . self::$post_type_1 . 's' ); 
}
```

With something like the above you can add capabilities the roles.

You should also do this to remove all rights for the type `post`.

`$wp_roles->remove_cap( ... )`

As hint to the source. The `self::$post_type_1` is a variable in a class for the custom post type. The `foreach` loop is to add this capabilities often to different roles.